# Server.Transfer on ASP.NET doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My server method (void) is called by a javascript function and, int the end, it has to call another page using the Server.Transfer but it isn't happenning, the loaded page still the same (Default). Is a static method.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("Profile.aspx", true);
```

could someone help me ?

The JS script is:

function ChamarPerfil(valor) {

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'Default.aspx/ChamaPerfil',
    type: "POST",
    //data: parametros,
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'lat': valor.k, 'lng': valor.A }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"

});
```

Comment: There's not nearly enough information there to attempt a legitimate reply.  Have you set a breakpoint and tried stepping through the code in the debugger?

Comment: It sounds like you're making an AJAX request and ignoring the result.

Comment: Server.Transfer is not going to do anything inside some page method, handler or web service called from Javascript. Can you post your JS please ?

Comment: function ChamarPerfil(valor) {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'Default.aspx/ChamaPerfil',
        type: "POST",
        //data: parametros,
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'lat': valor.k, 'lng': valor.A }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"

    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell `Server.Transfer` won't work with an ajax call. It is designed to work with a full page, synchronous, postback. When you do a full page postback in asp.net, by default the server retunrs the same "page", `Server.Transfer` is used to return a different page.

With your ajax call you will need to redirect using javascript in the success call back using `document.location.href="profile.aspx"`

If you're redirecting, I'd say you are defeating the purpose of an ajax call anyway and just do it with a full page postback.